# How to get value of cell at current row GridView winforms devexpress

Tags: winforms, gridview, devexpress

I need to know which row I selected and get value of cell(Ex:idproduct) before to click Edit button.

Comment: If you are using DataSource you easily can cast the FocusedRow in your DataSource type and get the value. Else you need to handle the GetRowCellValue Method which is described in answers.

Answer (score 3):

As @brendon is referring to, if gridView is the current `View` on your `GridControl`:

```
// Get your currently selected grid row
var rowHandle = gridView.FocusedRowHandle;

// Get the value for the given column - convert to the type you're expecting
var obj = gridView.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "FieldName");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GridView's GetRowCellValue method to retrieve the focused row value.

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_GetRowCellValuetopic

See also: http://documentation.devexpress.com/windowsforms/CustomDocument753.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
    public int idproductx;

    public void tProductGridView_RowClick(object sender, RowClickEventArgs e)        
    {        
      if (e.Clicks > 0)      
        {        
          idproductx = (int)((GridView)sender).GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "idproduct ");                    
        }   
    }
```

Comment: You should developed your answer instead of just posting a solution unexplained.